# Printing a class attribute

Tags: python, class, attributeerror

Hi there I have the following code and I'm trying to print the object position, I am completely new to python & coding so need a bit of help!  This is the code I have;

```
class object:
def __init__(self, x, y, z, vx, vy, vz):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.z = z
    self.vx = vx
    self.vy = vy
    self.vz = vz

    def position(self):
        return '{} {} {}'.format(self.x, self.y, self.z)


obj_1 = object(random.random(), random.random(), random.random(), 0, 0, 0)


print(obj_1.position())
```

I get the following error message:

```
AttributeError: 'object' object has no attribute 'position'
```

Comment: check code indentation

Comment: Try changing the name of your class and inherit from object. `class MyClass(object)` and then `obj_1 = MyClass(...)` ;)

Comment: If the indentation you have is the one in your program, then yes, there is no method `position` in your object.

Comment: This should work if you fix your indentation. Although, do not use `object` as class name as it is already a builtin type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the indentation causing you a problem? I ran your code after fixing the indentation and it worked fine. Your `__init__` function just needed indenting.

```
import random

class object:

    def __init__(self, x, y, z, vx, vy, vz):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z
        self.vx = vx
        self.vy = vy
        self.vz = vz

    def position(self):
        return '{} {} {}'.format(self.x, self.y, self.z)


obj_1 = object(random.random(), random.random(), random.random(), 0, 0, 0)


print(obj_1.position())
```

Answer (score 0):

With fixed indentation:

```
class object:
    def __init__(self, x, y, z, vx, vy, vz):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z
        self.vx = vx
        self.vy = vy
        self.vz = vz

    def position(self):
        return '{} {} {}'.format(self.x, self.y,self.z)


obj_1 = object(random.random(), random.random(),random.random(), 0, 0, 0)


print(obj_1.position())
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked a like a treat!